# Error al subir jpeg y jpg en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo una api para subir imagenes pero la extension jpeg y jpg las sube dañadas.
En cambio .jfif y .png si las puedo visualizar bien con ese mismo codigo.
No me genera ninguna excepcion simplemente al querer abrirla me dice

```
 [HttpPatch("{IdCat}/{Id}")]
        public ActionResult PatchT(int IdCat, int Id, [FromForm] IFormFile file)
        {
            try
            {
               string main_path = "//xxx.xxx.0.21/recursos/";  
               string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(main_path, IdCat.ToString());
                //System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathString))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
                }

                var model = _context.AuditoriaFoto.Find(Id);
                if (model.Id == Id)
                {
                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).Substring(1);
                        var path = pathString + "/" + Id + "."+ extension;

                        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(path))
                        {
                            file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                        }

                        model.Ruta = path;
                        model.extension = extension;
                    }
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    return Ok(model);
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

[image: ejemplo]

Comment: A que te refieres con que sube dañados esos formatos de imagen.

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea  Hola he actualizado mi pregunta

Comment: Lo único que veo es que tienes el `copyasync`, pero tu método no es asíncrono, si intentas con `CopyTo`, o agregas a tu método `async`, y un `await` en tu copia, para que espere a que termine de copiar y continúe el proceso

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea tenia usted razon, eso me ha funcionado, pongalo como respuesta para aceptarla. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que veo en el código es que usas la función CopyToAsync, la cual es asíncrona, y tu método no, por lo que no esperara a que termine.

Lo que debes realizar es generar tu método async y un await en tu función CopyToAsync

```
public async ActionResult PatchT(int IdCat, int Id, [FromForm] IFormFile file){
    .
    .
    .
    await  file.CopyToAsync(stream);
    .
    .
{
```

O usar la función copyTo, la cual no es asíncrona.

```
public ActionResult PatchT(int IdCat, int Id, [FromForm] IFormFile file){
    .
    .
    .
    file.CopyTo(stream);
    .
    .
{
```